# QML SwipeView show all items at the same time

Tags: qt, qml, swipeview

When I add items  with a text in [**SwipeView**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-swipeview.html), it shows me, that all items are in the same place, If I'm looking to the preview the **SwipeView** working well.

**Code:**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        x: 195
        y: 133
        width: 200
        height: 200
        interactive: true
        currentIndex: 1
        clip: ture

        Item {
            id: hello

            Text {
                id: test
                text: qsTr("Hello")                    
            }
        }

        Item {
            id: bye

            Text {
                id: qrr
                text: qsTr("Bye")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is what I get:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [anchors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html) to your [SwipeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-swipeview.html), like this:

```
SwipeView {
    id: swipeView
    anchors.fill: parent
}
```

**Full code:**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        currentIndex: 1
        anchors.fill: parent

        Item {
            Text {
                text: qsTr("Hello")
            }
        }

        Item {
            Text {
                text: qsTr("Bye")
            }
        }
    }
}
```